# Validate if RichText field contains line breaks

Tags: validation-rule, richtextarea, line-break

I'm trying to create a validation rule that prevents users from having line breaks in a richtext field. Here's what I have:

```
Error condition formula: REGEX(Manual_Step_Description__c,"\n")
```

**I want to prevent this:**

> "Install the Smart vCard AppExchange app, and drag the buttons onto
>   the contact page layout.
>
> Create the context menu item "Export as vCard" in the Contacts grid
>   and point it to the vf download page"

**Should be this:**

> "Install the Smart vCard AppExchange app, and drag the buttons onto
>   the contact page layout. Create the context menu item "Export as
>   vCard" in the Contacts grid and point it to the vf download page"

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: did you try escaping like \\\n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately through formula, line break in the text cannot be identified.

There is a idea [Validate line breaks](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hUIqAAM) around this. You can vote for this idea.

Otherwise, through apex coding you can do this like below:

```
String str = [Select RichTextAreaField__c from Dealer__c where Id = '<recordId>'].RichTextAreaField__c ;

System.debug('str=' + str);

if(str.contains('<br>'))
{
    System.debug('line break found');    
}
else
{
    System.debug('no line break');
}
```